# JavaScript - Child inheritance breaks parent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, prototypal-inheritance

I'm still fairly new to prototypal inheritance in JS, and I'm running into a weird error I can't figure out. We're writing a game using canvas, and we have code that looks something like this:

```
function GameObject() {
    // Generic object that everything inherits from
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.dx = -0.5;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = "";
}

function Block(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width  = 2 * TILE_SIZE;
    this.height = 2 * TILE_SIZE;
    this.sprite.src = "images/block/block3.png";                      
    blocks.push(this); // Manager array
}

Block.prototype = new GameObject();
Block.prototype.constructor = Block;
```

This code works fine. Note that TILE_SIZE is defined in a separate file that is included AFTER the block script - this doesn't appear to be an issue here. But when we add the following code (after the Block function):

```
function Block_Turret(x,y) {}
Block_Turret.prototype = new Block();
Block_Turret.prototype.constructor = Block_Turret;
```

I get an Uncaught ReferenceError that TILE_SIZE is not defined in the Block function! It seems like the child is breaking the parent, and I have no idea why this would be the case  - this appears to be a fairly straightforward inheritance scenario. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first section code works because you're not *calling* the function that references `TILE_SIZE` (i.e. `Block`) until that second section of code, wherein the variable is referenced, and produces the reference error, since it is, as you explained, not yet defined. Nothing to do with inheritance, just plain old js.

To elaborate, the internals of the function are not executed until the function is called, so as long as the syntax is legal, there is no error, even if the function is defined, and even as you do, use it as a reference.

The structure should be changed. Configuration details, that are independent, should naturally be included before dependent code (think old C standards).

Comment: You're right - I moved all the configuration stuff before everything else and it appears to be working fine. Sort of a silly mistake, oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The TILE_SIZE has to be defined *before* you do `new Block();`